# Jquery append() stop adding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

heres my fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/ryuchix/o6dkbhfw/3/

When "VIDEO" is selected it display file input and a textarea. When Addmore is click it should add another textarea.

the problem appears in second appended div#container and select video and it doesn't add textarea anymore.

HTML

```
  <div id="container">
    <input type="text" name="itemname" id="itemname">
    <select name="type" class="type">
      <option value="text">text</option>
      <option value="video">video</option>
      <option value="image">image</option>
      <option value="file">file</option>
    </select><br>
    <div id="div-content">
      <textarea name="content" class="content"></textarea>
      <input type="file" name="file" class="file" style="display: none">
      <input type="file" name="file" class="image" style="display: none">
      <input type="file" name="file" class="video" style="display: none">
      <div id="div-prompt" style="display: none">
        <textarea name="prompt" class="prompt"></textarea>
        <a href="#" class="addprompt">add more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#" id="addmore">add more</a>
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ryuchix/o6dkbhfw/3/

Comment: Your fiddle seems to work fine for me. (Chrome, Windows 10)

Comment: The `Add more` button is working on your jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/o6dkbhfw/11/

Comment: I am able to reproduce the error by selecting add more in the first div and, choose video in the second and then add more (for textareas) does not work. You are creating multiple instances of the same IDs for your elements. A first step is to create unique IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are creating it dynamically I think you want this

```
  $('#container').on('click', '.addprompt', function (e) {
    $(this).parent('div').append('<div id="div-prompt"><textarea name="prompt" class="prompt"></textarea><a href="#" id="removeprompt">remove</a></div>');

  })
```

run snippet below

```js
// A $( document ).ready() block.
$( document ).ready(function(e) {
  select(); 
  var html = '<hr><div id="container"><input type="text" name="itemname" id="itemname"><select name="type" class="type"><option value="text">text</option><option value="video">video</option><option value="image">image</option><option value="file">file</option></select><br><div id="div-content"><textarea name="content" class="content"></textarea><input type="file" name="file" class="file" style="display: none"><input type="file" name="file" class="image" style="display: none"><input type="file" name="file" class="video" style="display: none"><div id="div-prompt" style="display: none"><textarea name="prompt" class="prompt"></textarea><a href="#" class="addprompt">add more</a></div></div><a href="#" id="remove">remove</a></div>';

  $('#addmore').click(function(e) {
    $('#container').append(html);
    select(); 
  })
  
  

  $('#container').on('click', '#remove', function (e) {
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
  })

  $('#div-prompt').on('click', '#removeprompt', function (e) {
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
  })
  
 

  $('#container').on('click', '.addprompt', function (e) {
    $(this).parent('div').append('<div id="div-prompt"><textarea name="prompt" class="prompt"></textarea><a href="#" id="removeprompt">remove</a></div>');
   
  })

});

function select() {
  $('.type').bind('change', function(event) {

    var i = $(this).val();


    if(i=="video"){ 
      $(this).siblings('#div-content').find('.content').hide();
      $(this).siblings('#div-content').find('.file').hide();
      $(this).siblings('#div-content').find('.image').hide();
      $(this).siblings('#div-content').find('.video').show();
      $(this).siblings('#div-content').find('#div-prompt').show();
    }
     else if(i=="image"){
      $(this).siblings('#div-content').find('.content').hide();
      $(this).siblings('#div-content').find('.file').hide();
      $(this).siblings('#div-content').find('.image').show();
      $(this).siblings('#div-content').find('.video').hide();
      $(this).siblings('#div-content').find('#div-prompt').hide();
    }else if(i=="file"){
      $(this).siblings('#div-content').find('.content').hide();
      $(this).siblings('#div-content').find('.file').show();
      $(this).siblings('#div-content').find('.image').hide();
      $(this).siblings('#div-content').find('.video').hide();
      $(this).siblings('#div-content').find('#div-prompt').hide();
    } else if(i=="text"){
      $(this).siblings('#div-content').find('.content').show();
      $(this).siblings('#div-content').find('.file').hide();
      $(this).siblings('#div-content').find('.image').hide();
      $(this).siblings('#div-content').find('.video').hide();
      $(this).siblings('#div-content').find('#div-prompt').hide();
    }

  });
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form style="margin: 0 auto; width: 50%">

  <div id="container">
    <input type="text" name="itemname" id="itemname">
    <select name="type" class="type">
      <option value="text">text</option>
      <option value="video">video</option>
      <option value="image">image</option>
      <option value="file">file</option>
    </select><br>
    <div id="div-content">
      <textarea name="content" class="content"></textarea>
      <input type="file" name="file" class="file" style="display: none">
      <input type="file" name="file" class="image" style="display: none">
      <input type="file" name="file" class="video" style="display: none">
      <div id="div-prompt" style="display: none">
        <textarea name="prompt" class="prompt"></textarea>
        <a href="#" class="addprompt">add more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#" id="addmore">add more</a>
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: well I would guess you are using an id #removeprompt. but you are making a bunch of them so you can't use an id. change it to a class just like you do for add prompt